# Non Admin users are not able to see all the language in "Language" dropdown in sitecore content tree

Tags: security, content-management-system, sitecore, user-roles, sitecore7.2

We are facing issue with non- admin user of sitecore.The admin user of sitecore can see all language which is there in Sitecore->System->Language, we have total 12 language there.
When we create user who is Sitecore client author and publisher and acess any content item then we only see 4 languages(i.e. en,en-gb,RU,ar-AE).
In Accessviewer we have given "Read,Write,Language:Read and Language:Write" permission on all the language except two but as I said I can see only four language after clicking on language button in popup and even for publishing also from non admin user I can see only these four languages. Let me know if I am missing any thing in configuration for content editor

Answer (score 0):

I was reading this [blog](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2010/06/30/setting-up-security-on-languages-in-sitecore-6/) article and it said the following:

> If you do not apply any permissions to a language then all members have write access.
>
> My users have now write access to one language only (or several languages if they a members of more than one language role). But they do not have write access to any content. This is done using trivial Sitecore security on the content. I use the Editor role for setting up read/write access to the content itself:

In his article his users have permissions the same roles, and similarly language restrictions. However it seems you need to explicitly go through content they should be able to edit also and give them permissions for that content.

Worth trying.

Comment: Thanks for sharing  your comment. We created some custom role using sitecore role.The problem was with the role.I tried only sitecore role for authoring and it works.

Comment: Do the missing languages display when clicking the more languages button in the languages drop down?

Comment: Yes @sobek....now I can see all languages....as mentioned above given the rights for Language Read and Write on the role for all missing language

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me after upgrade to Sitecore 10
at the beginning I was cleaning cache every now and then but the issue was coming back randomly then I found permanent solution below:
go to control panel-> Administration tools-> Database Cleanup-> Cleanup Invalid Language Data